# Automatically Redirecting Activity in Android

Tags: android, redirect, android-activity, postdelayed

I want to create a application where I can redirect from one activity to another activity automatically.
When I come back to first activity it shall redirect 1st activity to 2nd again.

Example:

act1--->act2(automatically)--->ac3--->ect....

Now using back button, however I reached act1 then it will again automatically redirect to act2.

I used the handler's postdelay method to redirect automatically but next time when I reached back first activity it become useless.

Comment: Change activity in onResume method

Comment: how hard is it, i still do not get you, when you use the back key its not effective?

Comment: startactivityforreslut(intent)  start intent for result 

onActivityResult()  call this method on result when come back from  any activity

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CheckActivity.class);
 startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE_CHECK);
```

*and get reslut In activity*

```
  @Override 
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
 { 
 if (requestCode == request_Code) {
    if (resultCode == REQUEST_CODE_CHECK) 
        Toast.makeText(this,data.getData().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();               
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your automatic redirecting Activity add the onResume method in the following way

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    startActivity(this, second activity intent);
}
```